# Javascript function to count nested array of object properties possibly using reduce/map

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, mapreduce, nested

I have a problem and I have looked at a few reduce questions on here and I just can't seem to wrap my head around a way to do this. I have an array of objects. Each object has the same properties, about 30 of them. Each of the properties has completely different types of information. I want to be able to create a new object/array easily. My example is below.

```
var array = [{parts: 12345, purchased: "yes", customerId: 12541},
             {parts: 12432, purchased: "no", customerId: 55514},
             {parts: 12345, purchased: "Yes", customerId: 44421}];
```

What I want to do is find a way to extract useful data depending on the type of information in the array. For example:

```
some_function(array) {
             ...
             return { parts: {uniquePart: 12345, timesListed: 2}};
             }
     }
```

I may also want to extend that returned object and count the number of times purchased was either yes or no. I have tried numerous approaches but I am thinking this is more a data model issue than a programming issue.

I am parsing this data off of strings of receipts. Once the plain text string is parsed I get a large 30 property object for each transaction. Some of the properties also are nested objects or arrays as well.

I want to correlate data across multiple transactions. Maybe I need to research a better way to approach this type of situation as a whole.

So I understand the question is a little vague but what I really want to know is what is the best way with the array given to end up with the following data structure:

```
{parts: {uniquePart: 12345, timeListed 2}}
```

I believe once I understand how to itterate through the nested array of objects and build the new object I can go from there. My current attempts using reduce have not yielded fruit.

```
array.reduce(acc,obj){return This is where I am a little lost}
```

Comment: Everything you describe is possible with chaining maps/filters and reduces, but you'll have to very explicitly define what outputs you'll need to create. Eg: I use a function that gets all unique values from an array, one that calculates occurences of object fields and then a 3rd that uses both functions to create the output structures. So define your outputs, write several simple reduces/maps, then reuse and combine.

Comment: this is a very vague question, you have to be more specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution features [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for a temporary object `count` and returns the wanted array with one object for every part.

```js
function getCount(array) {
    var count = {};
    array.forEach(function (a) {
        count[a.parts] = (count[a.parts] || 0) + 1;
    });
    return Object.keys(count).map(function (k) {
        return { parts: { uniquePart: k, timesListed: count[k] } };
    });
}

var array = [{ parts: 12345, purchased: "yes", customerId: 12541 }, { parts: 12432, purchased: "no", customerId: 55514 }, { parts: 12345, purchased: "Yes", customerId: 44421 }];
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(getCount(array), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. So if I understand the code correctly you create a temporary object count. This object contains something roughly similar to :
    { 12345:  0 or value + 1 )
you then run a map function which I am a little fuzzy on, but it basically takes the count object gets a list of keys, At this point Is where my lack of functional programming knowledge comes in. Could you explain the map function a little bit as you have used it here?

Comment: the map builds a new array. it returns for every element in the array - here the keys of the count object - a value. the value is in this case an object with one property parts and the wanted values.

Comment: Thanks so much, now I understand!